# POST SOAP request in python getting error Response: 403 Forbidden

Tags: python-2.7

Please can anyone help out? i am trying to POST a SOAP request in python but i am getting the error Response 403: Forbidden. my code looks like below:
i am using the python imports:

```
import httplib
 import base64
 import string


    #the message
    message = """<soap:Envelope ...rest message </soap:Envelope>"""

    host = "host.test.com"

    url = 'https://server.etc.com' #End point url
```

i need to use the Basic Authentication too so i need the username and password in the http header

```
username = 'username'
    password = 'password'

   webSoapAction = 'urn:etc-com:document...'


        #the Authentication in base64 encoding form for Basic Authentication
        auth = 'Basic' + string.strip(base64.encodestring(username +'.'+ password))

        webservice = httplib.HTTP(host) #connect to the server(host)
```

here i try to build the header:

```
webservice.putrequest("POST", url)
        webservice.putheader("Host", host)
        webservice.putheader("User-Agent", "Python http auth")


    webservice.putheader("Content-Type:", "text/xml; charset=\"UTF-8\"")
    webservice.putheader("Content-length", "%d" % len(message))
    webservice.putheader("SOAPAction",webSoapAction)

    webservice.putheader('Authorization', auth)

    webservice.endheaders()
    webservice.send(message)
```

i should get the response here

```
#get the response
    statuscode, statusmessage, header = webservice.getreply()
    print "Response: ", statuscode, statusmessage
    print "Headers: ",header
    res = webservice.getfile().read()
    print 'Content: ', res
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things regard to your basic auth header construction:

- Put a single space between "Basic" and your secret
- Use ':' instead of '.' in between username and password

So it should looks like:

```
#the Authentication in base64 encoding form for Basic Authentication
auth = 'Basic ' + string.strip(base64.encodestring(username +':'+ password))
```

Comment: Thanks Rex. Just tried that but it did not help as well.i dont know if it is related tousing http(host) or httpconnection(host). webservice = httplib.HTTP(host) webservice = httplib.HTTPConnection(host,80)